# Types of Regression Techniques?

Tags: machine-learning, regression, model-selection

Can someone explain types of Regression Techniques, and Where do we use?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various kinds of regression techniques available to make predictions. These techniques are mostly driven by three metrics (number of independent variables, type of dependent variables and shape of regression line).

```
Linear Regression
Polynomial Regression
Logistic Regression
Quantile Regression
Ridge Regression
Lasso Regression
Elastic Net Regression
Principal Components Regression (PCR)
Partial Least Squares (PLS) Regression
Support Vector Regression
Ordinal Regression
Poisson Regression
Negative Binomial Regression
Quasi Poisson Regression
Cox Regression
Tobit Regression
```

Find More at the below links

> https://www.listendata.com/2018/03/regression-analysis.html
>
> https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2015/08/comprehensive-guide-regression/
>
> https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/types-of-regression-techniques/
>
> http://www.urbanaseminary.org/types-of-regression-analysis/

If you want to choose your model based on "most used", you are wrong. you should choose based on the type of your input data and goal data and statistics of your data.

https://blog.minitab.com/blog/how-to-choose-the-best-regression-model

Comment: Your list is highly partial and incomplete. No wonder, since there are so many regression approaches out there. However, I think this does not qualify as a proper answer.

Comment: @Peter Yes, it is partial and incomplete. Thank you for pointing it. Now updated with the complete list.